# Detect the surfaces of a 3D mesh, selected by mouse

Tags: c++, 3d

I have an application that is used to display objects in 3D. Now I want to improve my application. If I double click in an area of my aillage, I want to retrieve them arrested and surfaces existing in this area, in order to subdivide this area then. Is it possible to receive them? Thanks.

Comment: Is this openGL or what lib are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this part "click in an area of my aillage, I want to retrieve them arrested"

Answer (score 0):

Convert the click on the viewport to a ray in world space.

Then query your scene with the ray to find intersecting objects (based on axis-aligned bounding box search using your scene's octtree, if you have one).

Then if you need to detect triangles, test the ray against all triangles in the objects found by the scene query.  You could optimize this step if necessary by building an octtree for the object's mesh.  The one that is closest to the ray origin is the hit point.

For each object you can transform the ray into its own local coordinate system.